# Can we optimize this MySQL SELECT Query (2 nested SELECTs & 2 INNER JOINs)

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

```
SELECT id,name,color
FROM animals a
INNER JOIN animal_tags atags ON atags.animal_id = a.id
WHERE atags.tag_id = 70 OR a.id IN (
SELECT a2.id FROM animals a2
WHERE a2.inherit_tags = 1 AND a2.species IN
(SELECT species.id FROM species
INNER JOIN species_tags stags ON stags.species_id = species.id
WHERE stags.tag_id = 70))
```

Basically, I am looking for any animal that either has an association with tag_id 70 (say "Fur") and any animal that belong to a species with an association with tag_id 70 AND where the animal is supposed to inherit its tags from the species.

My other option is to basically remove the inherit tags piece and just always define tags for animals... but somehow that doesn't seem very normalized. (Note that the *_tags tables just contain the relation and each tag_id has an association with the "tags" table where the tag details are stored. This is not important to this query, but just to show you that my table schema is fully normalized.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't actually need values from the tag table in your resultset, a complete join is not necessary. Often the query optimizer can more efficiently process a semi-join using `exists`.

Also, you're joining to intermediary tables (animal - species - speciesTags) when the species table is not necessary since you all three tables join on species_id. You can bypass species and join from animal to speciesTags.

Finally, since you already are using the animals table and you're evaluating an OR condition, there is no need to join that table to itself. This should prove to be more efficient. I would also make sure you have indexes on tag_id, species_id, etc.

```
SELECT id, name, color
FROM animals a
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 
               FROM animal_tags atags 
               where atags.tag_id = 70 
                   and atags.animal_id = a.id) 
    OR (a.inherit_tags = 1 
        AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 from species_tags stags
                   WHERE stags.species_id = a.species 
                        AND stags.tag_id = 70
                 )
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. This definitely looks better. Question: So is this query the way to go instead of defining tags for each and every animal? This is going in a PHP application and I am wondering what's better: running this query or defining tags for every animal and having a simple one-join query.

Comment: UPDATE: Your query excludes the one animal with a direct relationship with tag_id 70, and only includes the two items that are associated with a species associated with tag_id 70. The query below from Joe returns all three rows.

Comment: Both are legit approaches, personally I would probably have a single tags table and define tags at the animal level as I would rather have the overhead of the data over the overhead of the inheritance. A decade+ of writing code in the real world has led me to the "maximize data, minimize code" maxim. Now, I'm not advocating premature denormalization, but that is how I would design the table.

Comment: @user984512 I rewrote the query and can't see a situation where it wouldn't return an animal with a corresponding tag of 70 is the animal_tags table. I don't have data/schema to test against but it seems right. Basically return all animals where a corresponding record with tag_id 70 is in animal_tags or a tag id of 70 exists for the species of the given animal.

Comment: Sorry you are correct. Both mine and Joe's query contained a duplicate row. There should only be two rows. Thanks again! You actually optimized my query AND fixed it. (I know I could have added a GROUP BY animal ID there though, but I can see how I am grabbing more than what I need.)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this query should be equivalent.

```
SELECT id, name, color
    FROM animals a
        INNER JOIN animal_tags atags
            ON a.id = atags.animal_id
        LEFT JOIN species s
            INNER JOIN species_tags stags
                ON s.id = stags.species_id
                    AND stags.tag_id = 70
            ON a.species = s.id
                AND a.inherit_tags = 1
    WHERE atags.tag_id = 70
        OR s.id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you! That gives me the same results as the original query. I don't have a huge rowset to test its speed vs. the original query, but it definitely looks cleaner.

Comment: Is that correct on the first join: `animals.id = animal_tags.id`? Should that be `animals.id = animal_tags.animal_id`

Comment: @magicmike Yep. I saw that and corrected it about 9 minutes ago.

Comment: animal_id in animal_tags is a foreign key from aninals's id field. It's good.